# What is meant by array has been casted to associate the method with the correct child class?

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

I was practicing for AP comp sci A when I saw the following question:

An inheritance hierarchy is as follows:
The classes Dog, Snake, and Chimpanzee are child classes of the abstract class Animal.
What is the best explanation for why the code segment `animals[i].speak();` does not give us an error at run-time, assuming that the following line appears earlier in the code? `Animal[] animals = new Animal[10];`

(a) The `animals` array holds only references to Animal objects that have a `speak()` method defined in that child class.

(b) The `animals` array is cast as the correct child class explicitly so that the `speak()` method is associated with the correct child class.

(c) The `Animal` class has a method called `speak()` that is inherited and defined by all child classes.

(d) The `Animal` class is an instantiable class that has its own `speak()` method defined.

(e) The `Animal` class is a child class of `Dog`, which has a `speak()` method defined.

I am confused about options (a) and (b). Can anyone please explain what these options are saying?

Comment: The question asks for "the best explanation". If you don't understand some of the explanations then maybe these do not fall into the category of "best explanation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my interpretation of the options :

- The (a) option would suggest that only the child class Dog and Snake have a speak() method defined and that the `animals` array contains only Dog or Snake and no Chimpanzee.
- The (b) option would suggest that the `animals` array contains only instances of the parent class Animal and that those objects are cast during the execution to either Snake Dog or Chimpanzee to use the speak() method of the subclasses.

But the phrasing of the two option is weird, and it's unclear if it's the intended interpretation for the options.

Comment: I agree with what you're saying. I figured the reason all the instances have `.speak()` method is because it is defined in `Animal` otherwise it would fail to compile.

Answer (score 0):

Say `Dog` has a `.speak()` method, but `Snake` doesn't. You could cast an animal from the array to a `Dog` and use `.speak()`. Provided the array was only populated with `Dog` instances.

Since there is not casting (b) is not correct.

Option (a) sounds correct because `animals[i]` returns an `Animal` and it must have the method `.speak();`. The way the option is written though, it is suggesting that the array is only fill with `Animal` instances that have a `.speak()`, other instances might not have the method. If `Animal` did not have a method `speak()` method then this would not compile or run.